# Simulate Click Test with Enzyme/ Jest Not Calling Sinon Spy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, sinon

I have a React application that I'm building and I'm using Enzyme, Jest, and Sinon to test it. I've used sinon.spy() on other components in the app test validate that the onClick method was being called; however, it's not working with this particular component. I also know that onClick is indeed working when I run the app in browser. My test results yield a fail - "Expected: true; Received: false".

This component creates a list of buttons that redirect to a URL. The code for the component is as follows:

```js
import React from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
import {
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import styles from "./styles";

class ChannelList extends React.PureComponent {
    handleClick = channelURL => async event => {
      const {
        history,
        enterChannel
      } = this.props;
      await enterChannel(channelURL);
      history.push(`/chat/${channelURL}`);
    };

    render() {
      const {
        classes: {
          channelListContainer,
          channelButtonList,
          channelButton
        },
        channels
      } = this.props;
      return ( <
        div className = {
          channelListContainer
        } >
        <
        Paper >
        <
        List className = {
          channelButtonList
        }
        subheader = { < ListSubheader color = "primary" > Channels < /ListSubheader>} >
          {
            channels.map((channel, index) => {
              const {
                name,
                url
              } = channel;
              return ( 
              <div key = {
                  name + index.toString()
                } >
                <Button data - testid = {
                  `${name}${index.toString()}`
                }
                onClick = {
                  this.handleClick(url)
                }
                className = {
                  channelButton
                } >
                { name } 
                </Button> 
              </div>
              );
            })
          } 
          </List> 
          </Paper> 
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default withStyles(styles)(ChannelList);
```

And my test code is as follows:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  shallow
} from "enzyme";
import sinon from "sinon";
import ChannelList from "../ChannelList";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

describe("<ChannelList />", () => {
      const props = {
        channels: [{
            name: "test-channel1",
            url: "www.test1.com"
          },
          {
            name: "test-channel2",
            url: "www.test2.com"
          },
          {
            name: "test-channel3",
            url: "www.test3.com"
          }
        ]
      };

      let wrapper;

      beforeEach(() => {
          wrapper = shallow( <ChannelList { ...props}/>).dive();
      });

        test("handleClick is called when clicking on a list item", () => {
          const spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), "handleClick");
          const button1 = wrapper.find({
            "data-testid": "test-channel10"
          }).dive();
          expect(button1).toHaveLength(1);
          console.log(button1.debug());
          button1.simulate("click");
          expect(spy.called).toBe(true);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem: your `Button` elements have this prop:

```
onClick = {
      this.handleClick(url)
}
```

Rather than set the `onClick` callback to be `this.handleClick()`, it immediately calls `this.handleClick()` during the render, and then sets the `onClick` prop to be the return value of the function. Because this happens before you create the spy, the test fails.

You should probably do

```
onClick = {
   () => this.handleClick(url)
}
```

...or similar.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for looking at my issue! This spurred a secondary question. I'm relatively new to React, but are there performance implications with declaring a function within render? I'm assuming it's minimal in this case, since it's essentially just a function that calls another function. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not ideal, but from a code point of view sometimes it's better to take the hit (especially if you're not re-rendering often, or there's only a small number of instances being shown). You could get around it here by factoring out your channel button as a separate component, and then it could have an instance method called handleClick which would be able to access `this.props.channel` or whatever. In this case I'd say it's not worth it.